# How can I check if a directory contains packaged files?

Tags: package-management

I've just run into [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1308714). Somewhere while scrobbling round with `sudo pip`, I appear to have knackered my `dist-packages`. The suggested workaround is to [re]move `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and start again. I've had a look in the directory and it's pretty massive. Years of abuse.

I'm happy enough reinstalling everything with `pip` but I don't want to delete and then overwrite a load of packaged paths. In my experience, that's a recipe for agony.

I know we're talking about a `/usr/local/` directory here. These *should* be non-packaged files but I would like to make double-sure... And this might apply to other people who are in similar predicaments.

So is there a quick way I can list what packages a directory contains?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -S ...` can work well here. It's something I would normally use to check which package a specific file comes from but here we can use:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

This works because packages specify their file paths in full. If one contains a file `/usr/bin/file` it will specify the following as its paths:

```
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/file
```

---

I looked to see if `/usr/local/` had *any* packaged files (because it really shouldn't IMO) and found:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/local/
hl2250dnlpr, wine, shatter, cupswrapperhl2250dn, open-sankore: /usr/local
```

How very curious.

Comment: it shouldn't because such packages should get a lintian error (See http://lintian.debian.org/tags/file-in-usr-local.html)

Comment: @SylvainPineau I doubt any of these saw `lintian`. I know that `wine` used `checkinstall` (raises guilty hand) and the two `hl2250` packages used `alien` to convert from RPM... I can't speak for the other two... People who also didn't know what they were doing probably.